# Unauthenticated function in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

My App/Exceptions/Handler.php looks like

```
 protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
        }

        return redirect()->guest(route('customer.login'));
    }
```

And my browser shows this error everytime i access it.

```
This page isn’t working
127.0.0.1 redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

I'm a complete newbie so please be gentle with me :(

Comment: What middleware does your `customer.login` route use?

Comment: Can you show your routes file?

Comment: Post your routes file.